# Python / PyCharm missing argument 'self'?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm currently learning Python and I don't understand what is wrong with my code, but PyCharm keeps giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Sam/PycharmProjects/untitled1/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    fish1.bubbles()
TypeError: bubbles() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Here is my code:

```
import random
from Fish import Fish

fish1 = Fish
fish1.bubbles()

fish1.name = input("enter the name of your fish: ")
fish1.coords = ("({0},{1})".format(random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100)))

print("The fish's name is {0}, and it is swimming at co-ordinates{1}".format(fish1.name, fish1.coords))
```

and here is my Fish.py file:

```
class Fish:

    def __init__(self, name, coords):
        self.name = name
        self.coords = coords

    def bubbles(self):
        print("{0} blew some bubbles".format(self))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `fish = Fish()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the error in [Creating Instance Objects](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

In this section `fish1 = Fish` you didn't create the instance, but try to use it `fish1.bubbles()`.

So try change `fish1 = Fish` to `fish1 = Fish(name, coords)`.

`name` and `coords` required in your constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **call the constructor** of the [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) **to create an instance** of that [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

```
fish1 = Fish()
```

In your case it would be with parameters

```
fish = Fish("fish_name", "coordinates")
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Fish` is the class. You can't ask for an abstract fish to make bubbles. You have to ask a specific fish (that is, an *object* of that class). So, assuming your fish is "bob"

```
bob = Fish()
bob.bubbles()
```

Comment: Wouldn't you rather say, that `bob` is an *instance* of `Fish`?

Comment: @user8408080: which is also called an "object"